# Pig Latin exercise in Rust

Tags: rust, pig-latin

The title says it all. I'm reading "The Rust Programming Language" 2nd ed. right now, and just finished the "Collections" chapter. I know there's a ton of Pig Latin code here, but I think Rust deserves a separate question.

```
use std::io;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter the string to be Pig-latinized");

    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read from stdin");

    let s: Vec<char> = input.chars().collect();
    let mut new_s: Vec<char> = Vec::new();
    let consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q',
    't', 'r', 's', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q',
    'T', 'R', 'S', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z'];

    let mut i = 0;

    while i < s.len() {

        if !s[i].is_alphabetic() {
            new_s.push(s[i]);
            i += 1;
            continue;
        }

        let first_letter = s[i];
        let mut appendage: Vec<char> = "-hay".chars().collect();
        if consonants.contains(&first_letter) {
            appendage[1] = first_letter;
            i += 1;
        }

        while s[i].is_alphabetic() && i < s.len() {
            new_s.push(s[i]);
            i += 1;
            continue;
        }

        new_s.append(&mut appendage);
    }

    println!("{}", String::from_iter(new_s)); 
}
```

The code feels clunky, but I don't really know how to make it better. I'd love to see an idiomatic Rust solution!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For overall issues, these jump out:

1. `s[i].is_alphabetic() && i < s.len()` can panic, because you access the value before checking the length, it would have to be `i < s.len() && s[i].is_alphabetic()`.
2. `is_alphabetic` considers lots of things alphabetic that you probably don't want. If you [look at the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_alphabetic) the examples include `assert!('京'.is_alphabetic());` which probably isn't what you want.

For Rust itself:

1. Rather than converting the string to a vector of chars, it's easier to use an iterator. In your case it needs to be an iterator that can `.peek` so you can stop before consuming the character.
2. Pattern-matching can make the readability of checking the vowels vs others easier, and it allows you to collapse the logic in your first `if`. The matches also allow you to cleanly create and define the `suffix` value earlier, and avoid the usage of the problematic `is_alphabetic` function.

Here's an updated implementation:

```
let mut chars = input.chars().peekable();
let mut new_s = String::new();
while let Some(c) = chars.next() {
    let suffix = match c {
        'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' => {
            new_s.push(c);
            String::from("-hay")
        }
        'a'...'z' | 'A'...'Z' => {
            format!("-{}ay", c)
        }
        _ => {
            new_s.push(c);
            continue;
        }
    };

    while let Some(&c) = chars.peek() {
        match c {
            'a'...'z' | 'A'...'Z' => {
                chars.next();
                new_s.push(c);
            }
            _ => break,
        }
    }

    new_s += &suffix;
}
println!("{}", new_s);
```